# Embed font larger than char size in ImGui

Tags: c++, c++11, char, imgui

Im developing translation on little script that uses ImGui as frontend. I need extended set of unicode characters to be available in font that will be used. Since this script is injecting via DLL there's no way (I think so. I have no experience with c++ at all.) to use:

> io.Fonts->AddFontFromFileTTF("myfontfile.ttf", size_in_pixels);

Adding font from ttf file resulted in error that data == NULL;

```
void* data = ImFileLoadToMemory(filename, "rb", &data_size, 0);
if (!data)
{
    IM_ASSERT(0); // Could not load file.
    return NULL;
}
```

I've also tried to use io.Fonts->AddFontFromMemoryCompressedBase85TTF and compiling font by included binary_to_compressed_c but output is so big that I'm getting:

> fatal error C1091: compiler limit: string exceeds 65535 bytes in length

But function is not accepting any types except char*. I was connecting chars into string and then re-assemble it by str() and c_str() but app was crashing after injection. Here is function handling base85 conversion from ImGui:

```
ImFont* ImFontAtlas::AddFontFromMemoryCompressedBase85TTF(const char* compressed_ttf_data_base85, float size_pixels, const ImFontConfig* font_cfg, const ImWchar* glyph_ranges)
{
    int compressed_ttf_size = (((int)strlen(compressed_ttf_data_base85) + 4) / 5) * 4;
    void* compressed_ttf = ImGui::MemAlloc((size_t)compressed_ttf_size);
    Decode85((const unsigned char*)compressed_ttf_data_base85, (unsigned char*)compressed_ttf);
    ImFont* font = AddFontFromMemoryCompressedTTF(compressed_ttf, compressed_ttf_size, size_pixels, font_cfg, glyph_ranges);
    ImGui::MemFree(compressed_ttf);
    return font;
}
```

How I can fix this problem ? I've tried everything and nothing is working. Only passing smaller chars into compile function is working (Tried with bundled Cousine_Regular.ttf).

Answer (score 0):

I've found workaround this problem. If you really need to use BASE85 there's still no answer but you can increase your size limit by converting to int type (Dont put -base85 in binary_to_compressed_c.exe) then insert resulting table to header file and use instrucions provided by ImGui like so:

Header file:

```
// File: 'DroidSans.ttf' (190044 bytes)
// Exported using binary_to_compressed_c.cpp
static const unsigned int droid_compressed_size = 134345;
static const unsigned int droid_compressed_data[134348 / 4] =
```

Your import / render file:

```
static const ImWchar ranges[] = { 0x0020, 0x00FF, 0x0100, 0x017F, 0 };
//Because I need extended characters im passing my array to function.

io.Fonts->AddFontFromMemoryCompressedTTF(droid_compressed_data, droid_compressed_size, 16.0f, NULL, ranges);
```

That's getting rid of the problem about converting from string to char and other stuff related to base85 importing.